# New to ionic - can’t build for ios (9) on El Capitan, and sudo ionic is required, deprecated npmconf

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, npm, ionic-framework

I am a student and I just started with ionic today. I have no experience with command line usage so I am pretty stumped here.

When I try to run the basic template (tabs) with:

```
sudo ionic platform add ios
sudo ionic build ios
sudo ionic emulate ios
```

(these don't work without having the sudo there). 
the last one produces this in the logs (among other stuff above):

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/Dylan/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/D0923A6C-7738-41BA-8134-ED747069991A/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/Dylan/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/myApp.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/Dylan/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/Dylan/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/Dylan/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I have seen a few unsolved posts with the same errors but they haven't gotten anywhere. It could possibly be related to these following things here:

When running `sudo npm install -g cordova ionic` I get this warning:

`npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm`

Also, afterwards, if I try to run `ionic` I get a `-bash: ionic: command not found` error, but if I run `sudo ionic` then it logs a whole bunch of stuff to the console. Could this one be an error with security changes in El Capitan?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent having to **sudo** almost anything you do in **npm** while working on MAC, my best advice is:

**Install npm through [Node Version Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm)**.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I fixed this problem. Thanks anyway, and I'll leave this question here in case someone else with the same problem finds it.